# How can I pass a variable I defined in a jquery script to a PHP script?

Tags: php, jquery

My requirement is fairly simple...I want to drill down on a table row to display more detailed data below.  Thanks to several posts here and elsewhere, the jquery API site and various other resources I am sooooo close, but there seems to be one critical element I am missing.

I am able, in a single page to enter a value and submit that value as a variable to my PHP script.  And I am able using JQuery to click on a row in a table and have that pop up an alert that displays that data as a variable.  But I cannot pass the Jquery variable to my PHP script.  I have read so many posts with similar requirements, but none quite like this.

In the code below I want to use the $data variable that I have created when I click on a table row and post that to my PHP script.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.  Code below:

Thanks,

Rob

```
<?php
    require("dbconn.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>



<table border='1'>
 <tr>
    <th>user_name</th>
    <th>sec_level</th>
 </tr>

<tr>
    <td><a u_name="test">test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><a u_name="goat">goat</td>
    <td>goat</td>
 </tr>
 </table>


    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("tr").click(function() {
        var $data = ( $(this).find("a").attr("u_name") )
        alert( $data );
    });

    </script>


<form method="post" action="">
    <dl>
    <dt>Hobby No.
    <dd><input id="field_" name="dynfields[]" type="text">
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
</form>




<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit_val'])) { ?>
<?php } ?>

<body>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    if ($_POST['dynfields']) {
        foreach ( $_POST['dynfields'] as $key=>$value ) {
            $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        }
    }

    $q = "select * from my_hobbies where hobbies = '$values'";
    $r = mysql_query($q);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        echo '<br>'.$row[1];
    }
    mysql_free_result($r);
    mysql_close();
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when you pass that variable to the server?  If you want the page to be modified then you may as well simply post the form.  Can you give more information?

Comment: Either redirect to same page, submitting the variables using POST or GET methods. Alternatively, you can use Ajax if it suits the way use want to make us of the variables. If this doesn't solves your problem, then please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX..

```
$(function(){
    $(":submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Ajax.php",
            data:"WebName="+$("#WebName").val(),
            success:function(data){
            //...
            }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments - Archer/Sid - What I want is for the $data variable to be treated in the same way as the $dynfields variable.  ie when I click on the table row that contains the data "test", I want to post that data to my PHP script in the same way that it does if I enter the value "test" in the form box and press submit. When I do that I get the list of records appear on the same page where there is a match to the $dynfields parameter.